# При приближении фрактала, он приближается не в центр, а в левый верхний угол

Tags: python, numba, фракталы

Написал программу, создающую изображение множества Жюлиа, но приближение происходит не в центр, а в левый верхний угол. Вот код:

```py
from PIL import Image
from time import time
import numpy as np
import numba
import cv2

x = 1500
y = x
max_iter = 50

img = Image.new("RGB", (x, y), (0, 0, 0))

zoom = x // 2 + 1

pixels = np.array(img)

c = -0.65j
s = "-"
max_num = 2

texture = Image.open("texture_3.jpg")  # тут может быть любая картинка с любым градиентом
texture_size = min(texture.size) - 1
texture_array = np.array(texture)


def edit(c, s):
    return c
    if s == "-":
        return c - 0.002j
    return c + 0.002j


@numba.njit(fastmath=True, nogil=True, parallel=True)
def main(pixels: np.array, c: complex, zoom: int):
    for y2 in numba.prange(-zoom, zoom):
        for x2 in numba.prange(-zoom, zoom):
            if x2 + zoom > x - 1:
                break
            elif y2 + zoom > y - 1:
                break

            a = x2 / (zoom)
            b = y2 / (zoom)
            z = complex(a, b)
            num_iter = 0
            for _ in range(max_iter):
                z = z ** 2 + c
                if abs(z) > max_num:
                    break
                num_iter += 1
            col = int(texture_size * num_iter / max_iter)
            pixels[x2 + zoom, y2 + zoom] = texture_array[col, col]

    return pixels


while True:
    cv2.imshow("", main(pixels, c, zoom))
    cv2.waitKey(1)

    if c.imag > 2j.imag:
        s = "-"
    if c.imag < -2j.imag:
        s = "+"
    c = edit(c, s)
    zoom += 1
```

Помогите с этим разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переделайте цикл. Тогда *(0, 0)* из математики всегда будет отображён в середину экрана `(x // 2, y // 2)`:

```
for y2 in numba.prange(0, x):
    for x2 in numba.prange(0, y):
        a = (x2 - (x // 2)) / (zoom)
        b = (y2 - (y // 2)) / (zoom)
        z = complex(a, b)
        num_iter = 0
        for _ in range(max_iter):
            z = z ** 2 + c
            if abs(z) > max_num:
                break
            num_iter += 1
        col = int(texture_size * num_iter / max_iter)
        pixels[x2, y2] = texture_array[col, col]
```

Comment: Чувак ты легенда